# How to: Make a Div a link, but not the images within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for asking more questions about the same scenario but here goes:

My text is great, the images are placed perfectly, however, I don't want to jquery slide method to run when the images are clicked (those are saved for other functions). Is it possible to make the slide function run only when the 'block' to the left of the images is clicked?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<body>

    <div id="flip">
        <div id="flipBox"><p>Click to slide the panel down or up</p></div>
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="complete" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="add" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="edit" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="remove" height="32"     width="32" align="right" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
```

Here's the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/rvAPk/

I'm very grateful for SO's pool of knowledgeable people! Thanks guys!

-AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$("#flip img").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvAPk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(e){
    if(!($(e.target).is(".ux"))) {
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I have experienced event.stopPropagation() not working for some reasons in my actual development in Android browsers that I resorted to the same approach as above, i.e. checking the event target.

Answer (score 1):

following your example you can do like this...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(e){

    if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'IMG')
    return false;    
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<body>

    <div id="flip">
        <div id="flipBox"><p>Click to slide the panel down or up</p></div>
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="complete" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="add" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="edit" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="http://placekitten.com/32/32" alt="remove" height="32"     width="32" align="right" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
```